# Does dd act at the filesystem level or go to the raw device directly?

Tags: dd

Does `dd` act at the filesystem level or go to the raw device directly?

Comment: dd works on device level.

Comment: It depends on what you mean exactly. Technically it *always* reads the filesystem, or it wouldn't be able to determine, for one, the permissions of the regular file / device file or whatever is put to work on.

Answer (score 17):

`dd` works on whatever you chose it to work on.

You can take the terminal streams (stdin and stdout), or anything represented by a file descriptor as in- and output of `dd`.

And as almost everything on Linux has a file descriptor, you can use files, directories, character devices (e.g. `/dev/null`, `/dev/random`), block devices (e.g. partitions/file systems like `/dev/sda1` or directly entire disks like `/dev/sda`).

As you can see, `dd` is a pretty powerful and versatile tool, but make sure you use it with caution as it's also known as "**d**isk **d**estroyer" if you accidentally use it with unintended arguments.

If you're interested in more information about `dd`, read its manpage (run `man dd`) or look for example at [Answer to "dd vs cat — is dd still relevant these days?" (Unix&Linux.SE)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12538/74958) or [What does the command name "dd" stand for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/645689/367990)

Comment: Is `dd` powerful in itself or mostly takes advantage of the fact that *as almost everything on Linux has a file descriptor*?

Comment: @A.L Good question, I don't really know. You could look at its source code probably if you're interested. But does it matter?

Comment: No, that was just nitpicking about the assumption *`dd` is a pretty powerful and versatile tool*.

Comment: Check your command 5 times and write it on a piece of paper and check it another 5 times.  Mixing up IF and OF is instant destruction of potentially a lot of data.

Comment: `dd` has some nice features, but the most time it is used in ways which would work equally well with `cp`, `cat`, the shell ... [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12538/74958) some things which are hard without `dd` are listed. But `dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/ext/backup` can better be done with `cat /dev/sda > /mnt/ext/backup` for example

Comment: @Josef Thanks for the interesting comment, I included your link to my post.

Comment: +1 for mentioning **D**isk **D**estroyer...  **;-)**